# Asp.net core 3.0: get value from appsettins.json

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I am building an app in blazor using asp.net core 3.0, and I am new in using this framework, I am trying to access an value from appsetting.json into the .razor extension file.

I have added this reference at the top.

```
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
@inject IConfiguration Configuration


const int appsetting_value = Configuration["guidID"];
```

and I get error under Configuration["guidID"] saying: "a field initializer cannot reference the non-static field method or property.

Can any one help me with the solution will be much appricated.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you are doing right except return type is a string:

```
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
@inject IConfiguration Configuration

@{
    string appsetting_value = Configuration["guidID"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this if you want to get it in `@code` section:

```
int appsetting_value => Configuration.GetValue<int>("guidID");
```